What is the source if you see something bad in someone else it means it's something you have to fix yourself?
BH
Hi, I heard that the Alter Rebbe's Chassidim would have an avoda where they said "If you see something bad in someone else it means it's something you have to fix within yourself." What is the source of this? One Rav I asked said it might be from Toldot Yaakov Yoseph, although where exactly?

מום שבך…

It's usually said in the name of the Baal ahem tov.


כל הפוסל… במומו פוסל
Anyone who disqualifies [others]… he disqualifies [them] with his own blemish.

From מסכת קידושין (ע עמוד א׳).
Whoever gave you the notion that this is a purely Chassidic concept is mistaken. This idea was recorded millennia before Chassidism first came into existence.

The exact phrasing of this question avoids your rebuff about the origin of the idea, because the gemara didn't say you have to fix it. Fair, if you want to say that's obvious, what's not obvious is what the Baal Shem Tov did reveal - that by fixing it within you, you fix it within them. The exact wording of the OP: If you see something bad in someone else it means it's something you have to fix within yourself. :) This gemara was quoted in the other answer and I'm sure in the Chassidus

All of the Torah existed far before the chassidic movement came to be. This should be an obvious statement but it doesn't negate how chassidus places emphasis or unique understanding

@RabbiKaii The “exact wording of the OP” doesn’t indicate anything other than what the Gemara does. Chassidut claims that fixing oneself fixes others in the same regard; however, that’s irrelevant to this question, which only mentions this Talmudic idea.

@Dude what unique understanding? The OP said a sentence. I sourced it. Anything else—including any Chassidic Chiddushim on this idea—is irrelevant to the question.

@Qwertrl if you want to tell me I am wrong, please respond to my argument directly, not my conclusion

@RabbiKaii Wrong in what way? I believe you about what Chassidut says. I disagree with the notion that my response doesn’t perfectly answer the question as currently phrased. This question isn’t about the בש״ט’s Chiddush, so neither is my answer.
